# nexus as a docker registry when nexus has a different root

Tags: docker-compose, nexus

I have a nexus server that acts as a repo for NPM, Maven and Docker artifacts.
The problem is that for NPM and Maven, for legacy reasons I had to serve all nexus from a different root i.e

```
[npm]
http://ip:port/nexus/repository/npm/
[maven]
http://ip:port/nexus/repository/maven/
```

and obviously by extension docker is `http://ip:port/nexus/repository/docker/`

but when docker tries to do anything it automatically goes as `https://ip:port/v2/` which of course results in a 404

Is there a way to specify the full url of the repo in the daemon.json rather than just host + port?

if I have anything else after port I cant start the daemon: `parsing "8081/nexus/repository/docker": invalid syntax`

Comment: to clarify Nexus responds only to `http://ip:port/nexus`, NOT to `http://ip:port` which is how docker-compose wants to build the request

Comment: Docker registries always need to run on web context path /, there isn't any way around that. So you'll need to configure a separate connector port for the repository.  You can find lots of info on this here:  https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/115013153887-Docker-Repository-Configuration-and-Client-Connection